# How to say that the teacher has marked my homework?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

How to translate this?

```
Today I reviewed the homework my teacher had marked.
```

Best I can do is

```
今天我复习了我老师会给我的作业
```

That's without saying the homework was assessed (and corrected).

Can't seem to find the right verb in the dictionary and I'm a little sketchy on the grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should say

```
今天我复习了我老师给我批改的作业
```

`批改` means correct. Or you can use `批阅`, which has similar meanning

Answer (score 3):

I would use 批:

> 今天我复习了我老师给我批下来的作业

Also, 复习 sounds a bit weird to me, since it means "review" as in "review for a test." If you're talking about corrections, 改正 will work better. If it's just looking over it, a simple 看 will do.

Answer (score 2):

I always use `检查` for marking homework or classwork for that matter & my students use it back to me so I'm pretty sure it's okay.

`改错` is also a very common word for correcting marked homework/classwork - so I don't know if you ever need to go back and correct your own mistakes but if so you can use this.

Answer (score 2):

修改 or just 改 is the most common way of expressing "mark" in this context. So I would translate your sentence as 我今天複習了我老師給我改的作業。

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding correcting/marking homework**

There are many ways to say "correcting/marking homework". The most formal name of the action is "批改" of which 批 means commenting the homework and 改 means correcting the homework.

Many words in modern Chinese are constructed in this manner which is a combination of two characters have similar meaning.

With that being said, when casual conversations, people do not say "批改". Instead, there are several single character verbs:

***判 pan4***

判作业, mark homework.

老师判你的作业了吗？ Have the teacher corrected your homework?

Personally, I prefer using this one, and it's widely used in places like Beijing, as far as I know.

***批 pi1***

批作业, mark homework.

老师批你的作业了吗？ Have the teacher corrected your homework?

When I was a student, I normally wouldn't use this one, but some teachers does. Personally I don't like using it in this scenario as 批 also has the meaning of criticise, which also used to refer to the action that teacher or parents scolding a child.

***改 tai3***

改作业, correct homework.

This is more widely used in Taiwan, and maybe some southern areas of China. Personally I don't use it either as it may be mistaken as the action of correcting the mistakes in homework. For example:

> I corrected Tom's homework
>
> 我 改了      汤姆的 作业

There is no way to know whether 改 means to mark Tom's homework as a teacher or to correct the errors in Tom's homework without context and inference.

**Regarding reviewing homework**

The dictionary translation of review is 复习 in this settings. But 复习 literally means to study again or to study again to prepare for a test. See the examples bellow.

- When it just means to study again. For this meaning you can also use the word 温习

> Teacher: you should review what you learned today after school.
>
> 老师：放学后你们应该复习/温习你们今天学到的（内容）。

- When it means to prepare for a test

> Student A: Have you prepared for the today's test?
>
> 学生A：今天的考试你复习了吗？
>
> Student B: I meant to, but I spend the whole night playing Diablo III last night somehow.
>
> 学生B：我本来打算复习的，但是不知怎么的，晚了一晚上的暗黑破坏神3。

As you may noticed both scenarios don't fit quite well with your example. In your case review means to look or view again where "again" here is not very important as the homework is already finished and corrected. So the sentence could be modified and translated as following:

> Today I reviewed the homework my teacher had marked.
>
> = Today I inspected the homework my teacher had marked. | Today I took a look at the homework my teacher had marked.
>
> = 今天我检查了我的老师给判/改/批的作业 | 今天我看了我的老师给我判/改/批的作业

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to use: "今天我溫习了老師批改的功课。”
1. In Chinese, we don't need to specify "my teacher". Instead of "我老師”，just “老師” is enough.
2. When I use "溫习”，it means "revision". It seems to be more natural.
3. When you use "homework", "功课” first comes to mind though "作业” is of similar meaning.
4. "批改” can be a stand-alone verb. This makes the sentence flow smoothly.

N.B. I am a Chinese born in Hong Kong. We study Chinese all the way from kindergarten till now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to: "今天我复习了老师给我布置的作业。"
maybe forgot at all~! :-)

Comment: One part that's incorrect: "the homework my teacher had marked" is not "老师给我布置的作业" - the latter doesn't express that it's a previously completed homework that has been marked.